# 2D array how to avoid the same numbers

Tags: java

Good evening I want to fill a five x five table with different numbers I do not want to have the same number for each column I have limitation that should be, belong to a certain limits, I was able to do but do not know how to avoid to be no more than once the numbers in the table

```
int num;
        int [][] array = new int [5][5];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) { 
            if(row == 0){
                     num =r.nextInt(15);
                    array[row][col]=num;
            }else if(row == 1){
                     num =r.nextInt(31-16)+16;
                    array[row][col]=num;
            }else if(row == 2){
                     num =r.nextInt(45-31)+31;
                    array[row][col]=num;
            }else if(row == 3){
                     num =r.nextInt(61-46)+46;
                    array[row][col]=num;
            }else if(row == 4){
                     num =r.nextInt(75-61)+61;
                    array[row][col]=num;
            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a range of numbers defined?

Comment: You could always make a magic square

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row, create a list containing the integers it can contain, then shuffle the list (with `Collections.shuffle()`), and keep the 5 first elements.

Or, if your goal is to have different elements for the whole table, create a single list containing all the integers the matrix can contain, then shuffle the list, an iterate through the list to fill your matrix.

Comment: Thank you allot i make it , i use an array and the 'list.contains(num)'

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `HashSet` of the numbers already taken. Add to this and duplicated are not allowed. Use the `toArray()` method to get the array object if needed.

If you still want to use the arrays then the `add()` method of `HashMap` returns `true` if the value did not exist in the current set so if `true` then add to the table, if `false` then don't.

This allows you to add elements to the table without having to shuffle i.e. if you want to continually update the table and not have to wait for a full set before displaying.

That is assuming you just want the numbers to be unique for the table and not just the row positions.